# Spring-Security OAuth WebMVC Invalid CORS request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security, cors

Hopefully my final question to get all this working. Using Spring Security OAuth 2.0.8 and Spring-Web MVC 4.2.3 to expose the OAuth endpoints (the majority of the system uses RESTEasy for the REST endpoints, which has its own CORS filter).

I am trying to use the global default CORS support that is now in Web MVC 4.2.x. However, when issuing a test preflight request against the /oauth/token endpoint, I am always getting returned a 403 Invalid CORS Request response. Sample request from Fiddler is below.

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/myapp/oauth/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://testfakeorigin.overtherainbow.com
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
```

Even though this goes through and is determined to be a proper preflight request, it looks like the request fails in DefaultCorsProcessor at line 81 because the CorsConfiguration is null. Even if I explicitly add a CORS registry mapping in my WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (which shouldn't be necessary according to the docs), the config still ends up being null. Where should I look next?

Comment: check out my answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/55463965/1848555

Answer (score 0):

Before the actual `POST`, you might automatically be issuing an `OPTIONS` request. By [default](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cors.html#_global_cors_configuration), only the method that is specified in your `RequestMapping` is allowed. Therefore, you will have to explicitly allow the `OPTIONS` method for the cross origin request.

One way to do that, using the global configuration, is as follows:

```
@Override
public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
    registry.addMapping("/**").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "OPTIONS").allowedOrigins("http://testfakeorigin.overtherainbow.com");
}
```

This would enable cross origin requests for all you mapped requests using the `GET`, `POST`, and `OPTIONS` methods.

Comment: I did that but for me it didn't work, as you can see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307591/java-spring-rest-api-cors-not-working-for-delete-requests-via-jquery-with-chrome

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) of entire app in your @Configuration class, that way all your controllers will be override automatically. Take a look:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity( debug = true )
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
     /* ... configurations */
     @Bean
     public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues();
        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
        config.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
     }
}
```

Note: you can define the methods verbs that will applied in your config

Best Regards!