# Java Spring REST API CORS not working for DELETE requests via jQuery with Chrome

Tags: java, jquery, spring, google-chrome, cors

I'm creating a web fronted written using jQuery which sends REST request to a REST Web Service written in Java using Spring framework. I'm facing a weird error with CORS requests. In particular, everything works fine if I use Safari; instead, with Chrome all DELETE requests fail (both GET and POST requests work fine in Chrome too).

The error I'm getting is:

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested 
resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access. 
The response had HTTP status code 403.
```

This happens when a first OPTIONS request is issued by Chrome.

My code regarding CORS is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfigurator extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**").allowedOrigins("*").allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "PUT", "OPTIONS");
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new CorsConfigurator();
    }

}
```

I also tried to add the `@CrossOrigin` annotations to my `@RestController` but nothing changed. Does somebody know ho to fix this?

Thank you,
Marco

Answer (score 0):

I just added `@CrossOrigin` to the method in controller and that fixed my problem

Answer (score 0):

I got this error in spring boot application and I resolved it by adding or enabling cors features as below

cors:
         allowed-origins: "http://localhost:8082"
         allowed-methods: "*"
         allowed-headers: "*"
         exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count"
         allow-credentials: true
         max-age: 1800